# iOS youtube player and AIR

Tags: ios, apache-flex, youtube-api

I'm developing application that  plays videos from youtube. On android it works well but i have problem with iOS. i know that iOS does not support flash etc. so are there any other alternatives how to play youtube videos in adobe air application that runs on iOS ?

tnx

Comment: How are you trying to get the videos to play?  Are you using StageVideo?  Or are you using something like SWFLoader?

Comment: i tryed with webStage and used youtube iframe video player. this works well, but i want to design own player but i dont know if its possible to stream directly from youtube in mp4 format.